# Neo4j - search chains. Cypher subquery on each node in path

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

In this image graph, I would like to find all the closed chain for node 1. In the route chains should include only those items for which there is a chain closed to all requests that are associated with this object.

[image: image graph]

```
MATCH mainChain=(n1:Object {id : 1})-[:NEEDLE]->(:Request)-->(x:Object)-[r*2..8]->(n1)
WITH mainChain as mainChain, x as x 
MATCH mainChainSubNodesRequests=(:Object)-->(:Request) 
WITH mainChain as mainChain, mainChainSubNodesRequests as mainChainSubNodesRequests, x as x
MATCH subNodesRequests=(x:Object)-->(:Request) 
WITH mainChain as mainChain, mainChainSubNodesRequests as mainChainSubNodesRequests, x as x, subNodesRequests as subNodesRequests
MATCH subNodesChains=(x:Object)-[*1..4]->(x:Object) 
WITH mainChain as mainChain, mainChainSubNodesRequests as mainChainSubNodesRequests, x as x, subNodesRequests as subNodesRequests, subNodesChains as subNodesChains, count(subNodesRequests) as subNodesRequestsCount, count(subNodesChains) as subNodesChainsCount 
WHERE (x)-[:NEEDLE]->(:Request)-[*]->(x) AND (subNodesChainsCount == subNodesRequestsCount) 
return mainChain
```

I am trying to compare the number of chains have nodes with the amount of requests nodes. Stuck ....
Please, help

Comment: Added sample for testing  
[Example graph neo4j](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=opkdd3)  
In the example of the link, the node numbers do not coincide with the image. Here is an example of right and wrong route for this example  

succesfully chain = 3->4->5->6->3  
bad chain (route) =  3->4->0->1->5->6->3

Comment: Not clear what your looking for... what is a needle relationship...